# Как создать переобучение нейронных сетей

Tags: нейронные-сети

Обучаю нейронную сеть методом обратного распространения ошибки. Преподаватель попросил продемонстрировать переобучение сети. Пробовала задавать усложненную структуру сети и большое количество эпох, не помогло. Как по-другому можно этого добиться и/или на каких данных?

Answer (score 1):

Переобучение сети всегда выглядит примерно одинаково. С точки зерния поведения функции ошибки на контрольном множестве, вы будите получать следующее:

[image: Кривая ошибки на контрольном множестве]

Так, все точки, через которые проходит кривая -- это точки train set, остальные относятся к test set. Если посмотреть на данные, то будет примерно следующее.

[image: Пример переобучения]

Самым простым способом переобучить сеть -- это подольше подождать. Но, например, если Вы используете линейный перцептрон, то вероятно достичь переобучения будет нельзя, так как все минимумы функции ошибки примерно равнозначны по отношению к искомой точке глобального минимума, которую, кстати говоря нельзя построить в данном случае. Это происходит потому что она принадлежит к другому множеству точек. Об этом можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE). А выглядит это примерно [так](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bd/Production_Possibilities_Pareto_Curve.png?uselang=ru). Т.е. оптимальная точка Х лежит вне рассматриваемого для персептрона множества, а значит недостижима.